# Unable to execute SQL Query Error : Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named 'Emp' in the database

Tags: sql-server

[image]

```
use mydatabase 
create table Emp(EmpNo int primary key,EmpName varchar(max),Salary money)
select * from Emp
insert into Emp values(111,'rama',1000)
```

Unable to execute SQL Query Error : Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named 'Emp' in the database.

Comment: A table with the same name already existing. Please check before re-running create script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The create table statement is throwing an error because you cannot create two tables in the database with the same name.

If you want to keep the create table statement in your code block try using the below code.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Emp') 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Emp(
        EmpNo int primary key,
        EmpName varchar(max),
        Salary money)
END
```

The above code block will create the table if it does not already exist.
If you want the table to be created new each time the query runs so you can empty the table and update its structure use the below code.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Emp') DROP TABLE Emp

CREATE TABLE Emp(
        EmpNo int primary key,
        EmpName varchar(max),
        Salary money)
```

Comment: You mean `IF NOT EXISTS` on your first example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe the `Emp` table already exists, possibly due to having been created earlier.  You can try dropping it if it already exists:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Emp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Emp;
```

And then continue as you were:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp(EmpNo int primary key, EmpName varchar(max), Salary money)
SELECT * FROM Emp
INSERT INTO Emp VALUES (111, 'rama', 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

1. first please click on the database name you create example if the name of the data base you create is Bill payment then click on the Bill payment;
2. then Programmability;
3. and then press on stored procedure;
4. then press on the above NEW QUERY.